# How do I use registerForActivityResult to launch Camera?

Tags: java, android

Since startActivityForResult is deprecated, I'm trying figure how to launch Camera using the new method.

Comment: I have no idea how to use. I looked everywhere. I use do the startActivityForResult without the contract, but its been deprecated so Its telling me to change it to ActivityResultLauncher, which I'm not familiar with. And I am try putting this code in and its showing me its incompatible with Intent, I have to change it <Intent> to <Uri>

Comment: Please add necessary details to your question. One liner question are not helpful for community. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Take photo and put it into some imageView. Camera permission required

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

In the Activity:

```
if(permissionGranted){
    pickCamera();
}

Uri cam_uri;

public void pickCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
    cam_uri = requireContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cam_uri);

    //startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE); // OLD WAY
    startCamera.launch(cameraIntent); // VERY NEW WAY
}
```

In `onCreate` of the Activity:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startCamera = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                mImageView.setImageURI(cam_uri);
                }
            }
        }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, you may add some more validations but `registerForActivityResult` is used.

**EDIT:**

`TakePicture` as **ianhanniballake** mentioned is a simpler way

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
           // stuff here                  
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the [`TakePicturePreview`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview) or [`TakePicture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture) contracts which do this work for you? There's no reason to use `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult` for this.

Comment: I have no idea how to use. I looked everywhere. I use do the startActivityForResult without the contract, but its been deprecated so Its telling me to  change it to ActivityResultLauncher, which I'm not familiar with. And I am try putting this code in and its showing me its incompatible with Intent, I have to change it <Intent> to <Uri>.